# Can't connect to Metamask from js

Tags: javascript, ethereum, metamask

I am trying web3 and creating NFT by myself for learning.
I could make my ethereum network and now connect js to Metamask.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"></script>
<script type='application/javascript'>
  var provider;
  var signer;
  var myAddress;

  // Connect to Metamask
  async function connectWallet() {
    provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
    signer = provider.getSigner();
    myAddress = await signer.getAddress();
    document.getElementById('connect-button').remove();
    document.getElementById('wallet-address').innerHTML = myAddress;
    document.getElementById('wallet-info').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }

</script>
```

It above returns error: `ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: missing provider (argument="provider", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.2.0)`.
As far as I see, there is no other parameters to pass `ethers.providers.Web3Provider` and could not find people who have same error.
What is wrong with me ? Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have metamask installed?

Comment: Yes. I could build ethereum network and connect it to Metamask. Even smartcontract is deployed on my ethereum network and NFT itself is minted to my wallet in Metamask. Only js connecting metamask has a problem

Comment: In your browser console does `window.ethereum` returns an object? I ran your snippet and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: No. It returns "undefined".

Comment: I could solve the error. Thank you!

Comment: @TIshow how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You're facing this error because you are serving the page as a static HTML page. consider serving the HTML page using node.js

add app.js to your project directory and paste the below code:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

connect()
    .use(serveStatic(__dirname))
    .listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on 3000...'));
```

1. `npm install connect serve-static`
2. `node app.js`

You can now go to `http://localhost:3000/yourfile.html`